# Image not getting displayed in ImageView in mobile but working in AVD

Tags: android, image, android-intent

I tried creating a new intent to get an image file and on result of the intent i got the image uri and set to the imageView but this worked fine in my AVD and even in Bluestacks but is NOT working in my phone (installed after converting to an apk). Image selection screen appears but then after selecting the image only a blank gets displayed in the imageView.

here's my code for on click the imgView

```
imgView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select contact Image"),1);
        }
    });
```

my on Result from intent method

```
 public void onActivityResult(int reqCode,int resCode,Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(reqCode,resCode,data);

    if(resCode==RESULT_OK) if (reqCode == 1) {

        imgView.setImageURI(data.getData());
        imgUri = data.getData();
    }

}
```

Note: My image View is a scaled image view of 100*100 px

Comment: Looks like resolution issue. Where's you image located (the path)?

Comment: The path of image is storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/xyz.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this instead

```
//this code calls the app or phone to pick an image from the gallery    
    pick = 0;
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(i, pick);
```

and in the activity on result use this

```
//process image gotten from gallery
                if (requestCode == pick && resultCode == getApplicationContext().RESULT_OK) {

                    Uri imgUri = data.getData();
Bitmap bitmap = null;

                try {
                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(imgUri));
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                ImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

}
```

Comment: This also leads to no image getting loaded .

Comment: Sry your code works great but i did not include permission Read External Storage.